# Hidden field not updated from ASP.net javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Trying to update a hidden field value by running a javascript from asp.net code behind. The code below is in an asyncfileuploader uploadcomplete.

```
If (Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("lowResTrue")) Then
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript _
   (Me.GetType(), "lowResTrue", "lowResTrue();", True)
End If
```

Javascript

```
function lowResTrue() { 
  document.getElementById('lowResHidden').value = 1;
  alert('currval true: ' + document.getElementById('lowResHidden').value);
}
```

The alert above shows "1" as it should. But when I run another javascript it has not changed the value to "1". It seams like the ASP.net trigger of the javascript is not updating the page. Any ideas?

Comment: What is "another javascript"? When is it run, what does it do?

Comment: Only show the hidden value. alert(document.getElementById('lowResHidden').value); But it seams like the asyncfileuploader causes a page load and all the values seams to reset. Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: When is this javascript run? Also it seems like there is some page update in place. How is it done?

Comment: I read the value after imageuploadcomplete.  It seams like the page load is just before the server saves the file. But I don't get why the hidden field value does not remain...??

Comment: If you are posting something to server, then `Page_Load` is triggered beyond question. You have posted too little info about your code to give a more detailed answer.